Why is my Flask API with PyCaret model slow on Kubernetes but fast locally?
I’ve built a Flask API that uses PyCaret for model building and prediction. When I run the application locally, it performs well, completing requests quickly. However, when I deploy the same application to a Kubernetes (k8s) cluster, it becomes significantly slower.
